# How to exit the try block after breaking in a foreach

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, foreach, try-catch

How to exit the Try block and return if I encounter a break in one of the foreach. I am able to get the break working properly, but it then enters the next foreach :D haha :) Its funny :p Should I try returning inside try block? Please help correcting my code.

```
public void function()
{
  Response() response= new Response();
  try
   {
     1st Foreach ( if condition met, break; )
     2nd Foreach ( if condition met, break; )
     3rd Foreach ( if condition met, break; )
   }
catch( Exception e)
{
}
 return response;
}
```

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, maybe to use `return` instead of `break`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: I think good point, let me try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: `1st Foreach ( if condition met, return response; )` then do it for the other blocks too.

Comment: This may be one of the rare situations a `goto` is ok.

Comment: Re: **Q:** _Should I try returning inside try block?_ **A:** _Yes_. If you return from inside your `try`, everything continues to work as you would expect.  The `catch` doesn't matter, if your `return` executes, then an exception hasn't happened.  Your `finally` code will run after the statement with the `return` executes, but before the function actually returns to the caller.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: That was the trick, your answer helped me. All others, thank you so much

Comment: Not really enough in the example to suggest the right way. You talk about returning and even do so in the catch but your function is void return type. Are your for each loops iterating the same types of ienumerables? Is your predicate test the same or different for each of the for eaches?

Comment: @Pretasoc NO! :)

Comment: @RufusL If you can't return from a deep nested loop `goto` can be useful. It has to be used carefully but in this situation it fulfills its purpose.

Comment: @Pretasoc I hope you noticed the smiley face - I was half joking with you. And perhaps there is some situation where it would be useful, but in this situation you *can* return from the loops (with `return`).

Comment: @RufusL I saw the smiley face but since i know that `goto` is a dangerous topic i wanted to make my point as clear as possible. So no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must fix the return type of your `Function` to return `Response`. An yes, return right the `response` directly.

```
    public Response Function()
    {
        var response = new Response();
        try
        {
            foreach (...)
            {
                if (... /* condition met */)
                    return response;
            }
            foreach (...)
            {
                if (... /* condition met */)
                    return response;
            }
            foreach (...)
            {
                if (... /* condition met */)
                    return response;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return response;
    }
```